# Pythonic way to check if field in Mongodb Document exists on a conditional

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

All the answers that I've read shows to use the following code to find out if the field exists **in the collection**. :

```
db.inventory.find( { qty: { $exists: true, $ne: false } } )
```

I was looking for something that conditionally checks in the current document being checked has that certain field/key. Ofcourse I tried doing something like:

```
doc['properties.color'] is None:
     print("Property does not exists")
```

But my documents have made it harder. Not all my document has that property within a field therefore causing an error:

```
KeyError: u'properties.color'
```

That is why I needed the conditional statement while I loop at every document. I hope someone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general opinion is that the pythonic way is to ask for forgiveness instead of permission.

Assuming the code snippet you posted is in a context like this:

```
if doc['properties.color'] is None:
    print("Property does not exists")
else:
    # do something with doc['properties.color'], e.g.:
    color = doc['properties.color']
```

If you ask for forgiveness instead of permission, you work with the error you are facing instead of against it:

```
try:
    # do something with doc['properties.color'], e.g.:
    color = doc['properties.color']
except KeyError:
    # this would be your `if`-branch from above
    # handle this case:
    print("Property does not exist")
```

Comment: haha :) that was quite a refreshing way to answer. Thanks! I'll try to keep this in mind whenever I encounter conditionals like this from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Using pymongo you can check just like you check on a dictionary.
For example:

```
document = collection.find_one({"author_id": author_id})
if "author_username" in document:
    print("Author has a username)
```